# 'else' without a previous 'if'

Tags: c, if-statement

I have this piece of code, and I guess that it is pretty easy to understand what I am trying to do. However I get an error saying something like

> the last else is called without an if before it.

I suspect that the problem is my if-else statement in between the `if` and `else`. How can I solve it?

```
int talet;
scanf("%d", &talet);

int i = 1;
while (i <= 99) {
  int a; {
    if (i % talet == 0 || talet == (i / 10) % 10 || talet == i % 10) {
      if (talet % 10 == 0)
        printf("\n");
      else
        continue;
    }
    printf("burr ");
    else
      printf("%d ", i);
  }
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Simply watch your brace placement one more time. They are all over the place.

Comment: When posting code, consistent indenting is important for readability. Also, tabs don't work well on this site so make sure to use spaces instead. Also, with consistent indenting, your problem is pretty obvious.

Comment: "*I guess that it is pretty easy to understand what I am trying to do.*" No, it isn't. From what should we conclude how you want the output to look like?

Comment: Thank you for tips. As I said, this is my first actual project and so I wasn't really focusing on the structure itself as I had been informed that indentation doesnt really matter as opose to in Python where every space matters. I will think about that. Also with the brace placements, I just got the point of them. I thought u had to have {if (condition) { //If statement} else //else statement}. Now I got it! Cheers

Comment: @diaco indentation matters for *our* readability, not for how the compiler understands the code. In this case, the indenting *hid* how the compiler was seeing the code. Also, a good IDE or editor might be able to help you with tools to automatically indent and/or highlight matching `{` and `}`.

Comment: Good on all those answers suggesting you change to a sensible bracing style.. To me looking at the code it's rather obvious print("burr " ); occurs between the if and the else.

Comment: @CashCow Yes... At the time, I had only been programming the basics of Python, and was thrown into C with a 1 week introduction, at uni. The bracing style was a bit hard to understand, but today, I obviously see that it was all over the place haha...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your brackets. Indenting is important to understand where to open and close your brackets

```
int talet;
scanf("%d",&talet);

int i=1;
while(i<=99)
{
int a;

    if (i%talet==0 || talet==(i/10)%10 ||talet==i%10)
    {
             if (talet%10==0)
                  printf("\n");
             else
                  continue;

        printf("burr ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
    i=i+1;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this works for you, happy I could help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is here:

```
}
    printf("burr ");  //<---
else
    printf("%d ",i);
```

You can't have any statements before the else block. So remove it or move it inside the else OR if block, something like this:

```
} else {
    printf("burr ");
    printf("%d ",i);
}
```

Comment: Problem is, I want that statement to be a part of the previous if-statement. I just dont want to repeat it in both the "if and else" of the "if", if you understand what I mean

Comment: @diaco Then just put it in the previous if statement?!

Comment: that was my intetion and I thought it actually was inside it now. Notice that I have previously been learning Python. Maybe that is why I am misunderstanding it. So everything inside { } is part of the if statement in other words?

Comment: @diaco Yes, if you have a code block (`{}`) with the if statement all inside of this is part if the if statement. e.g. `if (condition) { //If statement} else { //else statement}` And if don't have the brackets it's only the next statement. e.g. `if (condition) statement; else statement;`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have a `printf` outside the `if` brackets. Because of this, compiler thinks that the `if` statement finished. When it reaches the `else`, throws an error since there is no open `if` condition

You should have this

```
if (i%talet==0 || talet==(i/10)%10 ||talet==i%10)
{
    if (talet%10==0)
        printf("\n");
    else
        continue;

    printf("burr "); // <-- this was moved
}
else
    printf("%d ",i);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to keep your code-blocks as clean and readable as possible.
This will prevent you from making mistakes.

You can write an if else Horstmann style:

```
if (condition)
{
    #statements
}
else
{
    #statements
}
```

or a bit more compact in TBS1 style:

```
if (condition) {
    #statements
} else {
    #statements
}
```

choose one you like, more styles in the comment provided by crashmstr (thanks to him), and stick to it.
It WILL improve your code quality.

Comment: I don't know that I would call the first example "oldschool" nor would I associate the second example exclusively with Java. [Indent Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)