# Why is the std::vector not giving any outputs in c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, stdvector

I don't understand why but the std::vector is not giving anything after i put a class pointer in the array.

```
// runs at start
void States::AssignState(GameState* state) {
    _nextVacentState++;
    _states.push_back(state);
}

// executes in a loop
void States::ExecuteCurrentState() {
    // protection incase there is nothing in the array or the current state is not grater than the size of the array (not the problem after i nerrowed the problem down)
    if (_nextVacentState == 0) std::cout << "Error: There is no states, setup some states then try again" << std::endl; return; // there is no states
    if (_currentState >= _states.size() - 1) std::cout << "Error: Current State is grater than all possable states" << std::endl; return;
    
    // The program just freezes at this and i can figure out why
    _states[0]->tick();
    std::printf("S");
}
```

Comment: The target question mentions `else` but that's not relevant to the issue that you're facing, which is multiple statements intended to be enclosed by a `{}` but isn't.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Isn't the target I used correct? It's exactly the same issue as in this question, which is expecting that `{}` is not necessary. It's the best canonical I've been able to find for this question, but if you have a better one, I'd be happy to use it. This question has been asked *many* times before, and several times just this month. I'd be happy to share a list of such questions if you'd like to review them, and suggest a good canonical.

Comment: For reference, I'm suggesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325228 as a duplicate target here.

Comment: @cigien No, that question you propose is not the same issue as this question. The other question was using braces correctly, it simply had a typo in them, where the code was doing `if (...) { ... } <statement> else ...` The `<statement>` was just in the wrong place, as pointed out by several answers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, thanks for the feedback. I'll try and find a better target for this question about missing braces.

Comment: Agree on the need for a good canonical duplicate. We might have to fabricate one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the reasons I'd suggest getting in the habit of using curly braces for all `if` statements, even ones that live on a single line.

A problem line:

```cpp
if (_nextVacentState == 0) std::cout << "Error: There is no states, setup some states then try again" << std::endl; return;
```

Let's add some newlines to make it clearer what's happening

```cpp
if (_nextVacentState == 0) 
  std::cout << "Error: There is no states, setup some states then try again" << std::endl; 
  return;
```

That `return` statement is getting executed unconditionally, because *only* the first statement after `if(_nextVacentState==0)` is actually part of the `if`. So the compiler executes it *as if* it had been written like this:

```cpp
if (_nextVacentState == 0)
{
  std::cout << "Error: There is no states, setup some states then try again" << std::endl; 
}
return;
```

But, what you want needs to be written like this instead:

```cpp
if (_nextVacentState == 0) 
{
  std::cout << "Error: There is no states, setup some states then try again" << std::endl; 
  return;
}
```

You have same problem in the next `if` check for `_currentState`, as well.

Comment: thanks I though that was not the problem... I though wrong.

Comment: @GamingAllenAnimations When learning, write verbose code. Describe the behaviour you want very carefully. When you get more experience you'll find places you can comfortably cut corners, or you may find that cutting corners doesn't save you much time at all. Code is a description of program behaviour and not a list of instructions that will be run. The compiler will take your description and produce the optimal instructions, and these [need not look anything like what you wrote](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry to bother you, but could you review the target I used for this question (it's been reopened since I closed it)? If you have also have a better suggestion for a target, that would be great. This same question gets asked almost every week, and it would be nice to have a nice canonical target for them. Hopefully a good target will avoid needless reopens.